# The python-Docker container exits two second after running even with docker run -dit command

Tags: python, docker, api, kubernetes, containers

I wanted to test a custome kubernetes scheduler from [here](https://github.com/harshanarayana/kube-scheduler) with Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install kubernetes
COPY scheduler.py /scheduler.py
CMD python /scheduler.py
```

Once the image and container were created by:

```
docker build -t app . 
docker container run -d -it --name my-scheduler app:latest
```

Immediately the container went to **Exited** status.
Firstly I assumed that the process inside the container has ended because it hasn't run in kubernetes cluster yet.
So I craeted *deployment.yaml* and run:

```
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

and then checked:

```
kubectl get po -A
```

and as you can see pod is not ready:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY   STATUS         RESTARTS      AGE

kube-system   etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running        0             119s
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running        0             119s
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running        0             119s
kube-system   kube-proxy-8c7l5                   1/1     Running        0             107s
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running        0             119s
kube-system   my-scheduler-5f964589d7-pgg74      0/1     ErrImagePull   0             6s
kube-system   storage-provisioner                1/1     Running        1 (85s ago)   116s
```

I know there are many similar questions and answers in stackoverflow which I tried some of them which were not helpful for this case.

Comment: I see an `ErrImagePull`, which means that Kubernetes was unable to pull the imaged referenced in your deployment manifest. `kubectl get events` would show you more details about the problem, and if you were to post your deployment manifest we could probably provide more help.

Comment: By running `kubectl get events` all events are normal. If its nessacary I will send them. The deployment I used is [here](https://github.com/harshanarayana/kube-scheduler/blob/master/deployment.yaml).

Comment: You'll probably find it much easier to debug the container setup in plain Docker before involving Kubernetes at all.  Have you tried `docker run` the container without a `-d` flag to see what's in the container logs?  The Dockerfile seems fine; what's in the script you're trying to run?

Comment: The only issue is that in container log, the error `kubernetes.config.config_exception.ConfigException: Service host/port is not set` is exist. I thought that after running container with deployment the issue will be solved which did not.

Comment: @DavidMaze The python code is [here](https://github.com/harshanarayana/kube-scheduler/blob/master/scheduler.py).  I think all the issue is in `config.load_incluster_config()`.

Comment: You need to push your docker image, in this case `app` into a registry in order to be consumed by kubernetes

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman. I did this. Frist the status pf the pod was *ContainerCreating* and then *ImagePullBackOff*.